# Laravel database migration methods not working after deleting a migration file

Tags: php, laravel-5, database-migration

I am just beginning to learn laravel and so I am constantly dealing with migration methods right now. Previously, I have deleted a migration file `ShippedViaToPurchaseOrders` and after that I cannot perform `php artisan migrate:reset/rollback` anymore. What is the problem with this? Please help. Please take a look with the error below. Thank you so much.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are loaded using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), it still thinks the file is there.

Try running the `composer dump-autoload` command before running migrations to recreate the autoload file and let composer know the file is no longer there.

**Update:**

The Laravel migration tool creates a table `migrations` in your database to know what migrations have been executed. In this table, remove the row corresponding to the removed migration. 
Because the row is still there, Laravel will keep trying to run the rollback migration corresponding to that row.

Comment: The same error after running composer dump-autoload

Comment: I found it but can't edit or delete row..Can I drop the whole table?

Comment: You can drop the entire table, but then you will have to run all migrations again using `php artisan migrate`. All your data will be lost though.